# Json to C# object. Changing key:value pair

Tags: c#, json

I would like to know which object would correspond to this Json string. Generally I have no trouble, but here the numbers of the key:value pairs are always changing. So for example for the first one "22548421" next time it could be any number so I do not now how to handle that in C#. Thank you for you time.

```
{
"22548421": [
    {
        "name": "Jayce's Mercenaries",
        "tier": "SILVER",
        "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "22548421",
                "playerOrTeamName": "sifs",
                "division": "III",
                "leaguePoints": 63,
                "wins": 54,
                "losses": 49,
                "isHotStreak": true,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    }
],
"23380184": [
    {
        "name": "Darius's Blackguards",
        "tier": "GOLD",
        "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "23380184",
                "playerOrTeamName": "pantoflaman13",
                "division": "V",
                "leaguePoints": 19,
                "wins": 135,
                "losses": 130,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": true,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Zyra's Giants",
        "tier": "BRONZE",
        "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_3x3",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-3e523c50-f197-11e4-8964-782bcb48f791",
                "playerOrTeamName": "C4crew",
                "division": "I",
                "leaguePoints": 0,
                "wins": 4,
                "losses": 1,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    }
],
"31526913": [
    {
        "name": "Annie's Executioners",
        "tier": "GOLD",
        "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "31526913",
                "playerOrTeamName": "GDK Beshtiwan",
                "division": "V",
                "leaguePoints": 0,
                "wins": 192,
                "losses": 217,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": true,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Twitch's Mercenaries",
        "tier": "BRONZE",
        "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-50807400-bab5-11e4-b49d-782bcb4d190f",
                "playerOrTeamName": "Get Dunkid",
                "division": "I",
                "leaguePoints": 38,
                "wins": 6,
                "losses": 3,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    }
],
"33726623": [
    {
        "name": "Akali's Assassins",
        "tier": "SILVER",
        "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "33726623",
                "playerOrTeamName": "MPAMPHS GR 007",
                "division": "III",
                "leaguePoints": 0,
                "wins": 310,
                "losses": 306,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": true,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    }
],
"34887523": [
    {
        "name": "Akali's Gladiators",
        "tier": "SILVER",
        "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "34887523",
                "playerOrTeamName": "karpuzaotselo",
                "division": "III",
                "leaguePoints": 87,
                "wins": 121,
                "losses": 129,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": true,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    }
],
"36432092": [
    {
        "name": "Karthus's Army",
        "tier": "SILVER",
        "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "36432092",
                "playerOrTeamName": "Vol4mens",
                "division": "IV",
                "leaguePoints": 100,
                "wins": 115,
                "losses": 111,
                "isHotStreak": true,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false,
                "miniSeries": {
                    "target": 2,
                    "wins": 0,
                    "losses": 0,
                    "progress": "NNN"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Nasus's Swarm",
        "tier": "BRONZE",
        "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_3x3",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-02ac4070-d166-11e4-aad1-782bcb48f791",
                "playerOrTeamName": "League of Fitness",
                "division": "I",
                "leaguePoints": 12,
                "wins": 5,
                "losses": 4,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Annie's Cutthroats",
        "tier": "BRONZE",
        "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-02ac4070-d166-11e4-aad1-782bcb48f791",
                "playerOrTeamName": "League of Fitness",
                "division": "III",
                "leaguePoints": 9,
                "wins": 10,
                "losses": 11,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    }
],
"41537855": [
    {
        "name": "Sivir's Alliance",
        "tier": "SILVER",
        "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "41537855",
                "playerOrTeamName": "My name is daka",
                "division": "II",
                "leaguePoints": 57,
                "wins": 159,
                "losses": 169,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": true,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    }
],
"42498193": [
    {
        "name": "Viktor's Marauders",
        "tier": "SILVER",
        "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "42498193",
                "playerOrTeamName": "Exspy",
                "division": "II",
                "leaguePoints": 100,
                "wins": 288,
                "losses": 296,
                "isHotStreak": true,
                "isVeteran": true,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false,
                "miniSeries": {
                    "target": 2,
                    "wins": 1,
                    "losses": 0,
                    "progress": "WNN"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Nasus's Swarm",
        "tier": "BRONZE",
        "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_3x3",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-02ac4070-d166-11e4-aad1-782bcb48f791",
                "playerOrTeamName": "League of Fitness",
                "division": "I",
                "leaguePoints": 12,
                "wins": 5,
                "losses": 4,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Annie's Cutthroats",
        "tier": "BRONZE",
        "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-02ac4070-d166-11e4-aad1-782bcb48f791",
                "playerOrTeamName": "League of Fitness",
                "division": "III",
                "leaguePoints": 9,
                "wins": 10,
                "losses": 11,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Dr. Mundo's Tyrants",
        "tier": "BRONZE",
        "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_3x3",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-155bf680-0798-11e5-8e2b-782bcb46f3e4",
                "playerOrTeamName": "KokaKlucisKonstantins",
                "division": "II",
                "leaguePoints": 33,
                "wins": 5,
                "losses": 5,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Rengar's Warlords",
        "tier": "BRONZE",
        "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-155bf680-0798-11e5-8e2b-782bcb46f3e4",
                "playerOrTeamName": "KokaKlucisKonstantins",
                "division": "II",
                "leaguePoints": 21,
                "wins": 8,
                "losses": 5,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    }
],
"43463467": [
    {
        "name": "Janna's Runemasters",
        "tier": "SILVER",
        "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "43463467",
                "playerOrTeamName": "I luv Expoil",
                "division": "III",
                "leaguePoints": 100,
                "wins": 213,
                "losses": 237,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": true,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false,
                "miniSeries": {
                    "target": 2,
                    "wins": 1,
                    "losses": 0,
                    "progress": "WNN"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"52665047": [
    {
        "name": "LeBlanc's Duelists",
        "tier": "SILVER",
        "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "52665047",
                "playerOrTeamName": "Megoldom",
                "division": "II",
                "leaguePoints": 65,
                "wins": 204,
                "losses": 213,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": true,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Nami's Weaponmasters",
        "tier": "BRONZE",
        "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-c0b583f0-2f18-11e5-91f0-782bcb4d190f",
                "playerOrTeamName": "TeamThugLifes",
                "division": "IV",
                "leaguePoints": 0,
                "wins": 3,
                "losses": 2,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: where did you get this json?

Comment: It's from the League of Legends API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newtonsoft.Json does the job wonderfully. The only thing is that this scenario is not common :)

Below is the code of the Json Structure

```
 [JsonDictionary]
public class JsonClass : Dictionary<string, List<PlayerClass>>
{
}

public class PlayerClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tier { get; set; }
    public string queue { get; set; }
    public List<PlayerDetails> entries { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerDetails
{
    public string playerOrTeamId { get; set; }
    public string playerOrTeamName { get; set; }
    public string division { get; set; }
    public long leaguePoints { get; set; }
    public long wins { get; set; }
    public long losses { get; set; }
    public bool isHotStreak { get; set; }
    public bool isVeteran { get; set; }
    public bool isFreshBlood { get; set; }
    public bool isInactive { get; set; }
}
```

You can just use two lines of code to deserialize it

```
string jsonString = new StreamReader(File.Open("TextFile1.json", FileMode.Open)).ReadToEnd();
var deserializedOutput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(jsonString);
```

where `TextFile1.json` is a file which contains your `json`

Below is the deserialized output

[image]

PS: I Used version 7.0.1 of Newtonsoft.Json nuget package